# EU Vaccination Certificate and entering Canada

Tags: canada, covid-19, health, event-based-effects

I am a Canadian citizen planning to enter Canada from Europe and was vaccinated in Europe. If I upload my EU Vaccination Certificate to the ArriveCan app, will that serve as enough proof at the border? Do I have to translate my vaccine card? My card is very simple and if I were to translate it the only words on there are things like "Name", "Date of Birth", etc. So it doesn't seem like it would be necessary to do so, especially since the EU certificate is more official and already has that info in English.

Additionally, I understand that even though I'm fully vaccinated I need to present a quarantine plan. Does this mean I need to present a reservation for a 14-day hotel/Airbnb stay?

Comment: "Does this mean I need to present a reservation for a 14-day hotel/Airbnb stay?" You need to present a credible plan with somewhere to stay isolated for 14 days, be it a hotel, an Airbnb, your own apartment or your parents' basement (assuming other conditions can be met). See https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/isolation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.